# RSpec, Rails 4, Postgres, UUID primary keys: id is null with Rake + RSpec, but is fine in RSpec or console

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-postgresql

I'm trying to get up and running with UUID primary keys for a model with Postgres and Rails 4.0.0.rc2, but my specs are failing to create and destroy, yet `MyThing.create` or `MyThing#destroy` works fine from the rails console (in both dev and test environments). ...until I run specs, in which case doing either of those things stops working via the console.  Thus, it looks like something that happens when I run my specs that alters my DB and prohibits UUID keys from continuing to work.

Halp?

I followed [this blog post](http://labria.github.io/2013/04/28/rails-4-postgres-uuid-pk-guide/) to generate my migration, thus my schema looks like:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20130613174601) do
  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"
  enable_extension "uuid-ossp"

  create_table "growers", id: false, force: true do |t|
    t.uuid     "id",         null: false
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "code"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
end
```

Here's the progression of things:

Create:
`$ rake db:create RAILS_ENV=test`

Migrate:

```
$ rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
==  CreateGrowers: migrating ==================================================
-- enable_extension("uuid-ossp")
   -> 0.0052s
-- create_table(:growers, {:id=>:uuid})
   -> 0.0043s
==  CreateGrowers: migrated (0.0096s) =========================================
```

Create model object:

```
$ rails c test
agrian> g = Grower.create name: 'bobo'
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (4.1ms)  INSERT INTO "growers" ("created_at", "name", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Tue, 18 Jun 2013 20:22:39 UTC +00:00], ["name", "bobo"], ["updated_at", Tue, 18 Jun 2013 20:22:39 UTC +00:00]]
   (0.4ms)  COMMIT
=> #<Grower id: "38f84f39-e52e-4664-b776-4fdfcbd60b09", name: "bobo", code: nil, created_at: "2013-06-18 20:22:39", updated_at: "2013-06-18 20:22:39">
```

(rejoicing)

Run specs:

```
$ rake spec
/Users/sloveless/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p195/bin/ruby -S rspec ./spec/controllers/api/v1/growers_controller_spec.rb ./spec/helpers/growers_helper_spec.rb ./spec/models/grower_spec.rb ./spec/requests/api/v1/growers_spec.rb ./spec/routing/api/v1/growers_routing_spec.rb
...............FF..........F.*
(other stuff)
Finished in 0.30626 seconds
30 examples, 3 failures, 1 pending
```

Create model object:

```
$ rails c test
Loading test environment (Rails 4.0.0.rc2)
agrian> g = Grower.create name: 'bobo'
   (0.4ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (3.5ms)  INSERT INTO "growers" ("created_at", "name", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3)  [["created_at", Tue, 18 Jun 2013 20:29:36 UTC +00:00], ["name", "bobo"], ["updated_at", Tue, 18 Jun 2013 20:29:36 UTC +00:00]]
PG::Error: ERROR:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, bobo, null, 2013-06-18 20:29:36.773391, 2013-06-18 20:29:36.773391).
: INSERT INTO "growers" ("created_at", "name", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3)
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, bobo, null, 2013-06-18 20:29:36.773391, 2013-06-18 20:29:36.773391).
: INSERT INTO "growers" ("created_at", "name", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3)
from /Users/sloveless/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:780:in `get_last_result'
```

(sad face)

Can someone point me in the right direction here as to what might be doing silly stuff with my db?

**Update:** I can run `bin/rspec spec` over and over again with success (all my specs pass).  If I run `rake spec`, I get failures, then the next time I run `bin/rspec spec` I get failures.

**Edit:** Updated title to reflect rake + rspec problem, not just with rspec.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see that `rspec-rails/lib/rspec/rails/tasks/rspec.rake` defines this for the `spec` task:

```
spec_prereq = Rails.configuration.generators.options[:rails][:orm] == :active_record ?  "test:prepare" : :noop
task :noop do; end
task :default => :spec

# other stuff

desc "Run all specs in spec directory (excluding plugin specs)"
RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:spec => spec_prereq)
```

...which runs:

- `db:load_config`
- `db:test:purge`
- `db:test:load`
- `db:test:load_schema`
- `db:schema:load`

I see that, when running `rake db:schema:load`, I get:

```
-- enable_extension("plpgsql")
   -> 0.0161s
-- enable_extension("uuid-ossp")
   -> 0.0063s
-- create_table("growers", {:id=>false, :force=>true})
   -> 0.0049s
-- initialize_schema_migrations_table()
   -> 0.0062s
```

...which is different than when I run the migration:

```
==  CreateGrowers: migrating ==================================================
-- enable_extension("uuid-ossp")
   -> 0.0050s
-- create_table(:growers, {:id=>:uuid})
   -> 0.0052s
==  CreateGrowers: migrated (0.0103s) =========================================
```

Thus, it seems to me that the `db:schema:load` task isn't creating the table with the UUID primary key, thus causing the failures.  Seems like a Rails bug??

**Update:** I guess I'll find out if it's a Rails bug: [Issue 11016](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/11016)

Comment: Looks like they'll be fixing it in Rails 4.0.1. They should name the release after you.

Answer (score 2):

For others running into something similar:

```
# config/application.rb
config.active_record.schema_format :sql
```

In order to get postgres' `uuid_ossp` extension working, I needed to switch to an sql schema from schema.rb. It seems schema.rb tries to be more database neutral, which understandably results in some wonkiness with custom db extensions.

[See vikks comment](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/11016#issuecomment-31907859)